# How do I pass a parameter to a hook in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook, codeigniter-3

In CodeIgniter, how can I pass parameters from the context where the hook is called?

Example:

File_Where_Hook_is_Called.php:

```
$this->hooks = load_class('Hooks', 'core');

$filename = 'example.zip';

$this->hooks->call_hook('site_export_before_delete');
```

config/hooks.php:

```
$hook['site_export_before_delete'][] = array(
        'class'    => 'Foo',
        'function' => 'export_site',
        'filename' => 'Foo.php',
        'filepath' => 'modules/foo/controllers',
        'params'   => [''] # Should be $filename from File_Where_Hook_is_Called.php
);
```

application/modules/foo/controllers/Foo.php:

```
public function export_site($filename) {
    echo $filename); # Should print $filename from File_Where_Hook_is_Called.php
}
```

Comment: Might be possible with Codeigniters "Config Class" https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html#loading-a-config-file .... i checked codeigniters source code behide call_hook it's defined like `public function call_hook($which = '')` so it does not have a params which you can pass.

Comment: Yeah, I did that too. Kinda weird, right? Or is it an architectural choice?

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I ended up using global.

Answer (score 3):

I know it may be a bit late but I stumbled upon your question as I had the same need and I solved it in a correct manner.

According to the [CodeIgniter documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html) you can override the default CI_Hooks class behavior by implementing your own MY_Hooks class, usually at `application/core/MY_Hooks.php`

```php
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Hooks extends CI_Hooks{

    protected function _call_single_hook($data, $params) {
        if($params) {
            if(!isset($data['params'])) {
                $data['params'] = [];
            }
            $data['params'] = array_merge($data['params'], $params);
        }
        
        $this->_run_hook($data);
    }

    /**
     * Call Hook
     *
     * Calls a particular hook. Called by CodeIgniter.php.
     *
     * @uses    CI_Hooks::_run_hook()
     *
     * @param   string  $which  Hook name
     * @param   array   $params  Extra (dynamic) parameters array
     * @return  bool    TRUE on success or FALSE on failure
     */
    public function call_hook($which = '', $params=null)
    {
        if ( ! $this->enabled OR ! isset($this->hooks[$which]))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if (is_array($this->hooks[$which]) && ! isset($this->hooks[$which]['function']))
        {
            foreach ($this->hooks[$which] as $val)
            {
                $this->_call_single_hook($val, $params);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_call_single_hook($this->hooks[$which], $params);
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

In my case I extended the CI_Hooks class just overwriting the call_hook method, and the approach was appending extra parameters to the allowed "params" key of the hooks array.

After that you can invoke the hook from your controller.
Based upon your example, the code would be:

```php
$this->hooks->call_hook('site_export_before_delete', ['filename' => $filename]);
```

From my point of view, this is the good solution for the problem, and it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

#### It sucks, but use `global` scoped variable.

Since the function `call_hook` under CI_Hook class, does not take another parameter:

```
public function call_hook($which = '') {
   #...
}
```

And since I don't want to modify core files from CodeIgniter directly, I ended up using a global variable scope:

File_Where_Hook_is_Called.php:

```
# A variable with global scope should have an unique name,
# to avoid conflict with any other one in your entire application.
# Choose it carefully.

global $foo_hook_file_name;
$foo_hook_file_name = $file_name;
```

application/modules/foo/controllers/Foo.php:

```
public function export_site() {
    global $foo_hook_file_name;
    echo $foo_hook_file_name;
}
```

Just make sure to prefix the global var with a unique name, such as the name of the hook, to avoid conflicts with other variables.